# How to simplify a regex pattern?

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm here trying to simplify a regex.

What i tried was doing a repetition for the same expression, but when I tried to simplify it using ()*, it does not worked as it does not detect the pattern I want.

These are my regex:

```
(([\(]\w]{1,3}[\)])\s([\d]{1,3}[\?])([\(][\w]{1,3}[\)])\s[\d]{1,3}[\?]([\(][\w]{1,3}[\)])\s([\d]{1,3}[\?])([\(][\w]{1,3}[\)])\s[\d]{1,3}[\?]([\(][\w]{1,3}[\)])\s[0-9]{1,3}[\?]([\(][\w]{1,3}[\)])\s[\d]{1,3}[\?])
```

Whole pattern:

```
3A 1?(1) 2?(2) 3?(a) 4?(4) 5?(a) 6?(ii) 7?
4 6?(1) 7?(2) 8?(a) 9?(4) 10?(a) 11?(ii) 12?
```

These are the patterns it will detect:

```
1?(1) 2?(2) 3?(a) 4?(4) 5?(a) 6?(ii) 7?
```

The regex will detect **ONLY** the **first LINE** without the **3A**. How can I do these? 
The regex already be at it's simplest that is `\d+\?(?:\([\da-z]+\))?` , and now how can I put it in a way to detect **first line** only? Thanks guyss.

Comment: You can also remove a lot of unnecessary nesting. `[\w]`, `[\d]`, `[\)]`, and `[\?]` all mean the same thing without the brackets.

Comment: If i remove [], the whole regex will look messy and harder to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, here we can simplify it in another way, if it would be possible. For example, we might have three patterns, which we can capture it using three capturing groups: start, end and middle groups, possibly similar to:

```
(?:^\w+\s)|(\d\?\(\w+\)\s)|(?:\d+\?$)
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/IfUwEV/1), and add or reduce the boundaries that you wish.

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo for Capturing Groups

```js
const regex = /(?:^\w+\s)|(\d\?\(\w+\)\s)|(?:\d+\?$)/gm;
const str = `3A 4?(1) 5?(2) 6?(a) 7?(4) 8?(a) 9?(ii) 10?`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. but the pattern I want does not include 3A, it only detects start from the () until ? which is `4?(1) 5?(2) 6?(a) 7?(4) 8?(a) 9?(ii) 10?` I've edited the post to make it clearer..@Emma

Comment: I edited the questions on how the output should be. You may take a look :)

Comment: yes, the regex already detect the first line only but it includes 3A. How can  I exculde 3A ? @emma

Answer (score 0):

This pattern `([\(][\w]{1,3}[\)])\s[\d]{1,3}[\?]` does not match the leading `4?`

You could simplify the expression by remove the square brackets as you don't need them and add an optional part to match 1-3 digits followed by a question mark in front:

```
(?:\d{1,3}\?)?(\(\w{1,3}\))\s\d{1,3}\?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g6yogC/1)

If you don't want separate matches but 1 single match and the digits question mark part can also occur without the following part between the parenthesis , you could use a repeating group with an optional part for the parenthesis:

```
\d+\?(?:\(\w{1,3}\))?(?: \d+\?(?:\(\w{1,3}\))?)+
```

**Explanation**

- `\d+\?` Match 1+ digits and `?`
- `(?:\(\w{1,3}\))?` Optional group to match the parenthesis part
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d+\?(?:\(\w{1,3}\))?` Match 1+ digits and `?` followed by an optional part for the parenthesis
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g6yogC/2)

**Note**

In the first pattern of your example there is an opening bracket missing

```
(([\(][\w]{1,3}
      ^
```

In the second expression there is a closing parenthesis `)` to much at the end of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `\d+\?(?:\([\da-z]+\))?`

Explanation:

`\d+` - match one or more digits

`\?` - match `?` literally

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`\(` - match `(` literally

`[\da-z]+` - match one or more of either digit or lowercase letter

`\)` - match `)` literally

`?` - match at most one time preceeding pattern, which is `\([\da-z]+\)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jWD9aN/1)

Usage in code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim matches = Regex.Matches("3A 4?(1) 5?(2) 6?(a) 7?(4) 8?(a) 9?(ii) 10?", "\d+\?(?:\([\da-z]+\))?")
    For Each match As Match In matches
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**:

Try updated pattern: `^(?:\d+(?:\?(?:\([\da-z]+\))?|[A-Z]+) ?)+$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bcXaTR/1)

Comment: I edited the questions, sir. the regex will detect every possible pattern. What I want right now is to detect only first line. How can I do that?

Comment: I think I confused you, I'm sorry my bad >.< The pattern I wanted to detected was the first line only without including 3A.. I've edited my questions in my posts to avoid more confusion ..

Comment: @lara But second line contains patterns included in first line, why `6?(ii)` should be matched, while `11?(ii)` shouldn't?

Comment: i'm going to add increment for the first line only. the second will follow the increment after first line

Comment: @lara second line also increments, it is very unclear what you are aski ng and mist probably regex is not right tool for whatever you trying to do